# Line working in IntelliJ, giving an error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've recently had to migrate from IntelliJ to Eclipse, and even though both are using JDK 8 the line

```
frameRate = String.format("%s FPS", frameCount);
```

(where frameRate is a string and frameCount is an integer) throws an error in eclipse (stating `frameCount must be an Object[]`) while works perfectly fine in IntelliJ.

Comment: How did you set Eclipse to use JDK8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Eclipse is compiling your code with an older version of the JDK. Right click your project, go to `Properties`, go to `Java Compiler`, and set the compliance level to 8.

In previous versions of Java, the `String.format` method expected a `Object[]` as its second argument. In newer versions, the method uses a variable arity parameter of type `Object`.